# Using a while loop to print out a power table in Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to make a program that will print out a table of powers. The user is asked to provide the base, and then the maximum exponent. Then the program will print out a table of powers based on this information. For example, if the user typed in 2 for the base, and 4 for the max exponent, the program would first start at 2^1, then 2^2, then 2^3, and finally 2^4. I do not understand why what I wrote isn't working. I debugged, and saw that my base value is actually incrementing itself by 1 and I have no idea why.

```
def main():
   base=eval(input("Enter the base number: "))
   max=eval(input("Enter the maximum exponent "))
   counter = 1
   while counter<=max:
       base = base^counter
       counter = counter+1
       print(base)
main()
```

Comment: As a side note, don't use `max` as a variable name, it shadows the built-in function `max`.

Answer (score 2):

`^` operator give following result:

```
>>> 2^1
3
>>> 3^2
1
```

---

**Math Module**

Use `pow` method of `math` modules to generate power between numbers.

Demo:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.pow(2,2)
4.0
>>> math.pow(2,1)
2.0
>>> math.pow(2,3)
8.0
>>>
```

---

**Type Casting with Exception Handle**

Best practise to Type Casting to convert string to integer with exception handling because User might enter alpha values also.

The `eval()` will raise NameError exception when we try to eval alpha value.

Demo:

```
>>> eval("g")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'g' is not defined
>>> eval("2")
2
>>>
```

Type Casting with exception Handling:

```
>>> try:
...    a = int(raw_input("Enter digit:"))
... except ValueError:
...    print "Enter only digit."
...    a = 0
... 
Enter digit:e
Enter only digit.
```

---

Do not use built-in function name as user define variables.
`max` is built-in function in python.

```
>>> max
<built-in function max>
>>>
```

---

Code:

```
def generatePowerTable():
    try:
        base = int(raw_input("Enter the base number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print "Enter integer value only. Now base number 2 is selected."
        base = 2
    try:
        base_pow = int(raw_input("Enter the maximum exponent "))
    except:
        print "Enter integer value only. Now base max power 5 is selected."
        base_pow = 5

    for i in xrange(1, base_pow+1):
        rs = base**i
        print "%d ^ %d = %d"%(base, i, rs)

if __name__=="__main__":
    generatePowerTable()
```

Output:

```
$ python 3.py 
Enter the base number: 2
Enter the maximum exponent 5
2 ^ 1 = 2
2 ^ 2 = 4
2 ^ 3 = 8
2 ^ 4 = 16
2 ^ 5 = 32

$ python 3.py 
Enter the base number: e
Enter integer value only. Now base number 2 is selected.
Enter the maximum exponent r
Enter integer value only. Now base max power 5 is selected.
2 ^ 1 = 2
2 ^ 2 = 4
2 ^ 3 = 8
2 ^ 4 = 16
2 ^ 5 = 32
```

**Note:**
Use `raw_input()` and `xrange()` for `Python 2.x`

Use `input()` and `range()` for `Python 3.x`

Answer (score 1):

`base` changes in the `while` loop when you do `base = base^counter`, but you must keep it constant for what you want. Your solution is:

```
while counter <= max:
    res = base**counter
    counter += 1
    print(res)
```

*NOTE:* What your program is currently printing with an input of 2, 4 is `2^1`, `2^2`, `4^3`, `64^4`

Comment: thank you. Is the double asterisk sign the symbol for raising a number to a power in Python?

Comment: Yes, `^` is the bitwise `XOR`

Answer (score 1):

You can do also:

```
def potencia(x, y):
if y == 0:
    return 1
elif y == 1:
    return 0
pot = x ** y
return pot
print potencia(2,4)
```

output: 16

Answer (score 0):

Dont use the carrot (`^`) to do exponents. Use `**`

```
max = 25
counter = 1
base = 2

while counter != max:
    exp = base ** counter
    counter += 1
    print exp
```

Outputs:

`2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048
4096
8192
16384
32768
65536
131072
262144
524288
1048576
2097152
4194304
8388608
16777216`

Comment: you only have 24 results while your maximum is 25.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use a list comprehension. this eliminates the use of a counter and makes your code more readable (imo) and considerable shorter.

```
base=int(input("Enter the base number: "))
m=int(input("Enter the maximum exponent: "))

print[base**i for i in range(1,m+1)]
```